# Extended User model in django does not set fields when created even though arguments given

Tags: python, django, django-models

what happens is that when i create a new user using a registration form i created the user gets successfully created along with the extension which clearly has a field pointing to the User , however when i pass stuff like name or birthday during the creation process it is shown in the extended profile as None

here is my extension of User

```
class user(models.Model):
    account=models.OneToOneField(User)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthdate=models.DateField(default="1993-12-12")
    profilepicture=models.ManyToManyField('Photo',null=True, blank=True)  
    institute=models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    univeresitiesrated=models.ManyToManyField("university",null=True, blank=True)
    nationality=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    residence=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aboutself=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def create_user_callback(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    user1,new=user.objects.get_or_create(account=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_callback,sender=User,weak=False)
```

and my views.py

```
def UserRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
    if request.method=='POST':
            password=request.POST['password']
            newuser,created=User.objects.get_or_create(username=request.POST['username'],email=request.POST['email'])
            if created:
                newuser.set_password(password)
                newuser.save()
                userprofile=user(account=newuser,name=request.POST['name'],birthdate=request.POST['birthdate')

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')

    else:
        c={}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('register.html',c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're creating a Python object, but not doing it by using Django's `objects.create()` method, which also saves the object in the database.

If you want to create an instance with values, try this:

```
# save the instance
user_saved = user.objects.create(account = newuser, name = request.POST['name'], birthdate = request.POST['birthdate')

# retrieve the instance
user_retrieved = user.objects.get(account = newuser.id)
```

If you're retrieving an existing instance, and assigning field values, try this:

```
user_retrieved = user.objects.get(account = newuser.id)    
user_retrieved.name = "Raf"
user_retrieved.save()
```

The `objects.create()` method includes a call to `save()`, which is why you don't have to explicitly call it in the first example. If you create an object some other way, you'll have to call the `save()` method yourself. Similarly, if you retrieve an existing instance, and edit certain fields, you'll have to call `save()` to save the changes to the database. For more on saving Django model objects, take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

---

*By the way, the [Django `User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) class already has `first_name` and `last_name` fields, which you can use instead of defining a separate `name` field.*

*Also, the convention in Python is to capitalize the first letter of a class name. Functions usually use lowercase names. For this reason, it might be better to name your `user` class something like `Profile` or `StudentInfo`, as `User` already exists in Django.*